# Thread.sleep launching program after delay, not delaying

Tags: java, swing, thread-sleep

So I have a try/catch block

```
    try{
            Thread.sleep(400);
        } catch(Exception e){

        }
```

and this should, theoretically, just stop execution by 400 - however if i put it in here

```
for(char c : dialogue.toCharArray()){
        g2.drawString(String.valueOf(c),x,y);
        x += 10;
        try{
            Thread.sleep(400);
        } catch(Exception e){

        }
        if (x > 1000){                                                                                //replace with intended cutoff
            x = 75;                                                                                         
            y = y + 20;                                                                             //replace with actual height or whatever
        }
    }
```

it waits 400 and then launches the JFrame. How do I fix this?

Comment: Where do you set the frame as visible? `frame.setVisible();`

Comment: its not in this snippet, its earlier on

Comment: You should not be delaying in the event dispatch thread. Fork some worker that updates the gui at desired timeintervals.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.